# Sending several phrases to Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, home-automation

I'm trying to create a routine to where I can send several phrases to Alexa. From my understanding this is not possible (I miss my Google home :-( ). My lights are connected to a service to where I can't exactly control them as a device. It's pretty much 'Alexa, ask {my service} to turn off light 1'. I'm trying to set up something where I can send several phrases like below with a routine. Do I have to create a skill? Or what? Is there a way to create a scene? I do have home assistant, but I don't fill comfortable connecting my service to that.

- 'turn off light 1'
- 'turn off light 2'
- 'turn on light 3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it best to create a scene in my service. This is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try Alexa routines. You can control multiple devices with one command. You could start a morning routine, have the smart lights and smart coffee maker in the kitchen turn on...

https://www.amazon.com/alexa-routines/b?ie=UTF8&node=21442922011

Comment: I apologize, that's what I was trying to do: add several phrases in a routine. My solution was to create a scene turning on/off the lights in the service I was using and have Alexa trigger that scene in the routine. Thanks!